# keypress event not generated in Chrome on ENTER Key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

My application requires an input from users, on entering a value in a textbox, users hit Enter (Return Key) and this calls a 
buttons onclick event. This works fine in IE, FF  but not Chrome. On enter in chrome, keypress event is not generated
Here is my code snippet

```
 $('#myDiv').keypress(function (e) {
    alert("Key  pressed");
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {

     alert("enter pressed");
    }
  });
```

Could anyone provide input on this?

Comment: Could you show the HTML that goes with it? `#myDiv` sounds like you're not binding the event to the input field directly.

Comment: If `#myDiv` is an input field it's working in chrome, I just tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/PTauw/

Comment: i used keydown it worked

Comment: You need to come up with an example that shows the error. As jerome's jsfiddle shows, what you have in the question works fine on Chrome.

Comment: Ended up using a button for enter, none of the solutions would really work. Chrome needs to fix it. In firefox have no problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Cross-browsers method :

```
$('#myDiv').keydown( function(e) {
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if(key == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("enter pressed");
    }
});
```

Tested on Chrome 24 : http://jsfiddle.net/PTauw/1/

Comment: @techfoobar keydown is OK in this particular case but no better than keypress, which will work equally well. No need for the complicated `charCod`e / `keyCode` stuff, by the way: `keyCode` works in all major browsers for keydown and keyup.

Comment: @TimDown - Keypress is not reliable to use for ENTER (13) key (i think in fact for any non-print character). Had to resort to using keydown for cross-browser functionaing (experience from few recent projects)

Comment: @techfoobar: I'm pretty certain that keypress is 100% reliable for the enter key, which **is** printable anyway.

Comment: @TimDown - Ahh yes, i mean for arrow keys for which i had to resort to using keydown. My mistake.

Comment: Keypress does not work with chrome when you are trying to detect tab. You must use keydown to detect the tab.

Answer (score 6):

`keypress` is the correct event for detecting which character has been typed (although in this particular case, that of detecting the enter key, `keydown` would work just as well). However, how to get the character typed in a keypress event is inconsistent between browsers, so jQuery normalizes on the `which` property. Here's what you want:

```
$('#myDiv').keypress(function (e) {
    alert("Key pressed");
    if (e.which == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
        alert("enter pressed");
    }
});
```

The definitive reference for key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful for you...
[Api Jquery Key Press](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)
 or try with this code

Change keypress to keydown:

```
$('#myDiv').keydown(function(e) {

   // your logic
   alert("Key  pressed");
   if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
       alert("enter pressed");
   }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Chrome seems to be working with `ENTER` key and not `13`.

this works for me on all browsers including `CHROME`.

```
  $('#myDiv').keydown(function(e) {
       if ((e.which == 13) || (e.which == keyCode.ENTER)) {

    alert("enter pressed");
  }
```