# Bootstrap modal's button ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with my site

I have this modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade " id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content login-modal">
                <div class="modal-header login-modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="loginModalLabel">Autenticazione utente</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pError" Visible="false" runat="server">
                                <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger" id="confirm" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"> </asp:Label>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" id="pnl" class="login-tab">
                            <!-- SCHEDE -->
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a id="signin-taba" href="#home"  aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Accedi</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a id="signup-taba" href="#profile"  aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Registrati</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a id="forgetpass-taba" href="#forget_password" aria-controls="forget_password" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">Recupero</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <!-- LOGIN -->


                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div role="tabpanel"  class="tab-pane active text-center"  id="home">

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <%-- email --%>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginEmail"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </div>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vLoginEmail" runat="server" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtLoginEmail" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validator" ErrorMessage="*Email obbligatoria"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reLoginEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validator" ControlToValidate="txtLoginEmail" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Inserire l'email nel formato corretto" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                                            <asp:TextBox type="password" ID="txtLoginPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger" data-loading-text="Signing In...." ValidationGroup="validator" runat="server" Text="Accedi"></asp:Button>
                                    <input id="resetLogin" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" type="reset" value="reset" />

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="login-modal-footer">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="forgetpass-tab">Recupero </a>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="signup-tab">Registrati </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <%-- REGISTRAZIONE --%>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">

                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbUtente" GroupName="rbTipologia" Checked="true" runat="server" />Utente</label>

                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbRistoratore" GroupName="rbTipologia" runat="server" />Ristoratore</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>

                                            <%-- username --%>
                                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtNome" placeholder="Nome" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vtxtNome" runat="server" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtNome" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validator2" ErrorMessage="*Nome obbligatorio"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                    </div>
                                    <%-- cognome --%>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <div class="input-group ">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtCognome" placeholder="Cognome" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vCognome" runat="server" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtCognome" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validator2" ErrorMessage="*Cognome obbligatorio"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                    </div>
                                    <%-- email --%>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </div>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vEmail" runat="server" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validator2" ErrorMessage="*Email obbligatoria"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validator2" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Inserire l'email nel formato corretto" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </div>
                                    <%-- password --%>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <div class="input-group ">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                                            <asp:TextBox type="password" class="form-control" ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                        </div>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vPassword" runat="server" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validator2" ErrorMessage="*Password obbligatoria"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rePassword" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validator2" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="La password deve contenere: minimo 8 caratteri; almeno 1 maiuscola; almeno 1 minuscola; almeno 1 numero" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,15}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                                    </div>

                                    <%-- password controllo --%>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                                            <asp:TextBox type="password" class="form-control" ID="txtCPassword"  placeholder="Conferma password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvPassword" ValidationGroup="validator2" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="txtPassword" ControlToValidate="txtCPassword" ErrorMessage="La password non corrisponde"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRegistrazione" Visible="false" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                                    </div>




                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSignin" CssClass="btn btn-danger " data-loading-text="Registrando...." OnClick="btnSignin_Click" ValidationGroup="validator2" runat="server" Text="Registrati"></asp:Button>
                                    <input id="r2" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" type="reset" value="reset" />


                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="login-modal-footer">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="forgetpass-tab">Password dimenticata? </a>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="signin-tab">Registrati</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>


                                <div role="tabpanel"  class="tab-pane text-center"  id="forget_password">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <%--RECUPERO  --%>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtRecEmail" placeholder="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


                                        </div>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblRecovery" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vREmail" runat="server" Display="dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtRecEmail" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validator3" ErrorMessage="*Email obbligatoria"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reREmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validator3" ControlToValidate="txtRecEmail" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Inserire l'email nel formato corretto" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                                         </div>

                                    <asp:Button  ID="btnRecovery" OnClick="btnRecovery_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger reco" data-loading-text="Invio...." ValidationGroup="validator3"  runat="server"></asp:Button>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="login-modal-footer">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="signin-tab">Registrazione </a>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="signup-tab">Accesso </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

It has 3 tabs: Signin (LOGIN), Signup (Registrazione) and forgot password (RECUPERO).

It is a bit 'difficult to explain but I'll try:
In the 3 cards I have 3 buttons.
If I am in my third card and I press enter key, the computer triggers the onclick event of the button that is located on the first tab.

I tried this jquery code but it doesn't work:
$(document).keypress(function (event) {

```
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') {
            if ($('#home').is(":visible")) {

                $("#btnLogin").trigger("click");
            }
            else if ($('#profile').is(":visible")) {
                $("#btnSignin").trigger("click");

            }
            else {
                $('#btnRecovery').click(ShowPopUp);

            }

        }

    }
         );
```

Do you have any solution?

P.S.
If I use the browser's console the javascript code work, but when i try it on my project it doesn't work...

Please help me... this is my exam's project...

Comment: Is only one panel visible/enabled at any given time? That is what I am gathering from what I see

Comment: Also, you say your code works until you use it in your project. Have you tried stepping through it using IE or FF dev tools to see where it is falling apart while running it in your project? What is the difference in your implementation between the two instances?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the consideration :)

Gmley:   Yes is only one panel visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a local variable(in the jQuery load function) called `currentTab`
2. Create a click event for your tabs(`<li>` tags)
3. In the click event set the `currentTab` variable to the clicked `<li>`
4. Modify your `keypress` function to evaluate the currentTab variable and trigger the relevant click event

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {

           $("#show").click(function () {
               jQuery.noConflict();
               $("#loginModal").modal('show');

           });

           var currentTab = "";

           $(".nav li").click(function () {

               var li = $(this);
               var liText = li.text();
               currentTab = liText;
               alert('You clicked on "' + liText + '" now lets store this value in a variable called currentTab');
           });

           $(document).keydown(function (event) {

               debugger;

               var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
               if (keycode == '13') {

                   switch (currentTab) {
                       case "Accedi":
                           $("#btnLogin").trigger("click");
                           break;
                       case "Registrati":
                           $("#btnSignin").trigger("click");
                           break;
                       case "Recupero":
                           $("#btnRecovery").trigger("click");
                           break;
                   }
               }
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: I tried it on Microsoft Edge/ IE and it's work but when I try it on Google Chrome, it doesn't work...

Comment: Ok, Firefox has the same problem of Chrome...

So, the code works on Edge and IE but i doesn't work for Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Ctrl+shift+j in chrome and use the JavaScript console to debug the JavaScript and see what the problem is.And remember to mark as answered

Comment: I used the console but when I press the enter key in a tab different from the LOGIN tab , the jquery doesn't start because I have a required field validator on the LOGIN tab.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518412/keypress-event-not-generated-in-chrome-on-enter-key

Comment: Thanks for the help but still it does not work :(

I add only keydown and it give me the same error, for the requirefieldvalidator.

If i use this
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if(key == 13) { ........

the console does not give me any error, but nothing happens, as if it would not launch the javascript function...

Comment: Then maybe the problem is with the required field validator. Take it out and see if it works then.I edited my answer and included the complete java script that I used on my side to recreate your problem and it works in all the browsers

Comment: I'll try it, but in my opinion, the problem is not the requiredfield because I have it in all tabs but only the login tab use the requiredfield. I will let you know

Comment: I tried to do as you told me, but nothing always starts the click event of the "btnLogin" ...
I can not understand why on chrome and firefox is not working while on Edge and IE works

I am going crazy

Comment: Zip all your code and upload it on google docs.Send me the link and I will have a look at it tomorrow morning when I wake up

Comment: Ok, how can I send you in pvt?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwntYCUZmu9QRHRXTVFSZVFER1k/view?usp=sharing

This is the link :)